# How to change enumerate labels locally for one list?

Tags: lists, labels, renewcommand

I want to change list labels, but I don't want to do it globally. I want just this one special list have different formatting.

Overleaf instruction is:

> The command must be placed in the preamble to change the labels
> globally or right before \begin{enumerate} to change labels only in
> this list.

That would be perfect, but after test, code like this:

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item test
\end{enumerate}

\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\Roman{enumi}}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item test
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item test
\end{enumerate}
```

Gives following output:

[image]

As you can see, it's not changed globally. It's also not changed just for one list.

As expected `\renewcommand` does not simple disappear after one list. How do I get the desirable output? How do I reset labels or just cancel `\renewcommand`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the changes local to one `enumerate` environment, you could use a set of `{}`. Alternatively, you could also make use of  the `enumitem` package and use the optional argument of the `enumerate` environment to change its label.

Both approaches will result in the following output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item test
\end{enumerate}

{
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\Roman{enumi}}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item test
\end{enumerate}
}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item test
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item test
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\Roman*]
    \item test
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item test
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I feel so stupid now. THANK YOU. For my defense, I was fixed on the overleaf version, couldn't go outside of the box.